# Store array in while loop to use outside

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to store value from while loop but not in multidimensional way :

```
 $movies_id = array();

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title_id = $row['title_id'];
                    $movies_id[] = [$id => $title_id];
     }

print_r($movies_id);
```

I am not getting the way, how to do it, if i just write `$movies_id = [$id => $title_id];` it only shows the last value.

Thank you by advance.

Comment: $movies_id[] will add a element to array, it doesn't work?

Comment: which version of php are you using??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set value properly.

```
            $movies_id = array();

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title_id = $row['title_id'];
                    $movies_id[$id] = $title_id; // The proper way
                    //$movies_id[] = [$id => $title_id];
            }

            print_r($movies_id);
```

The more readable code would be:

```
            $movies_id = array();

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    $movies_id[$row['id']] = $row['title_id'];
            }
            print_r($movies_id);
```

And would result in

```
array (
    1 => 'Title 1',
    2 => 'Title 2',
    4 => 'Title 4',
    8 => 'Title 8',
)
```

And key-less soulution would be:

```
            $movies_id = array();

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    $movies_id[] = $row['title_id'];
            }
            print_r($movies_id);
```

And would result in

```
array (
    0 => 'Title 1',
    1 => 'Title 2',
    2 => 'Title 4',
    3 => 'Title 8',
)
```

Comment: Indeed are. But may be usable later if wanted to retrive ID of a movie.

Comment: there are a lot of ways but saying "you need" seems to be not optionals ;) that's for my downvote

Comment: Thanks, better be clear on what is optional and what it isn't =) so upvoted

Comment: Indeed. [$id => $title_id] led me to this mistake. By need i more meant he needs to do this that way if he wnats to store IDs as keys.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood what you're aiming for, but this might do it:

replace

```
$movies_id[] = [$id => $title_id];
```

with

```
 $movies_id[$id] = $title_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would not work in case of PHP version less than 5.4. In that case you can use the following.

```
        $movies_id = array();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title_id = $row['title_id'];
            $movies_id[] = array($id => $title_id);
        }

        print_r($movies_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line

```
$movies_id[] = [$id => $title_id];
```

Use the following

```
$movies_id[$id] = $title_id;
```

Comment: It will work, but it will make multidimensional array.
In the question user don't want multidimensional.

Comment: But the user does not want it to be multidimensional array. Have you read the question properly?

Comment: You have changed your comment just a minute ago.

Comment: See, SO is not for debating on a particular thing, It's about providing a beneficial solution to the question.

Comment: I changed the word "comment" to "question".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65753/discussion-between-hayk-aghabekyan-and-manish-jangir-blogaddition-com).