# Accessing an Array outside of a While loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a while loop which contains an array which is referencing another file: legProductionAllRecords.php. This file returns an array Which is then used in the loop. I want to be able to use the $orderArray in my javascript tableObj as shown however it is not working. And shows no results when I have no results in $inProgressArray. I also need to be able to use $inProgressArray outside of this loop.

**index.php**

```
$madeAt = 2;

$inProgressQuery ="SELECT * FROM leg_prod_inprogress WHERE madeat=".$madeAt;
$inProgressResult = mysql_query($inProgressQuery);
$orderArray = array();
$inProgressArray = array();

while($inProgressArray = mysql_fetch_array($inProgressResult,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $inPogressOrder = "-1";
    if ($inProgressArray != false) {
        $inPogressOrderNo = $inProgressArray['purchase_no'];
    } else {
         $inPogressOrderNo = -1;
    }
    require_once('legProductionAllRecords.php');
    $allArray = legProductionAllRecords($madeAt, $inPogressOrderNo);
    $orderArray = $allArray['allOrder'];
    $inPogressOrder = $allArray['inprocessOrder'];
    $toadyFinishedOrder = $allArray['todayFinishedOrder'];
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var tableObj = {
            data: <?php echo json_encode($orderArray); ?>,
            processingData:<?php 
                        if(!empty($inPogressOrder)&&$inPogressOrder!=''){
                             echo json_encode($inPogressOrder);
                        }
                        else{echo -1;} ?>,
        }
    </script>
 </head>
 </html>
```

**legProductionAllRecords.php**

```
<?php
function legProductionAllRecords($madeAt,$inPogressOrderNo){

$dayquery = "SELECT * FROM manufacturedat WHERE ManufacturedAtID=".$madeAt;//$madeAt is either 2 or 1
$dayresult = mysql_query($dayquery);
$dayArray = mysql_fetch_array($dayresult,MYSQL_ASSOC);
$day = $dayArray['LegCompletionNoItems'].' days';

$qry = "SELECT a.PURCHASE_No, a.legstyle, a.legfinish, a.LegQty, a.legheight, ".
    "a.addlegstyle, a.addlegfinish, a.AddLegQty, a.ORDER_NUMBER, a.specialinstructionslegs, ".
    "b.surname, b.first ".
    "FROM purchase AS a LEFT JOIN contact AS b ON a.contact_no=b.CONTACT_NO ".
    "WHERE a.legrequired='y' ".
    "AND a.completedorders = 'n' ".
    "AND a.quote = 'n' ".
    "AND a.orderonhold = 'n' ".
    "AND a.contact_no <> 326314 ".
    "AND a.contact_no <> 324273 ".
    "AND a.contact_no <> 313820 ".
    "AND a.ORDER_DATE >= '2015-12-31' ".
    "AND (a.cancelled IS NULL OR a.cancelled <> 'y') ";

$result = mysql_query($qry);
$orderArray = array();
$returnArray['inprocessOrder'] = null;
$returnArray['todayFinishedOrder'] = null;

while ($temp = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    if(!empty($temp)){
        $temp['surname'] = mb_convert_encoding($temp['surname'],"UTF-8");
        //$temp['title'] = mb_convert_encoding($temp['title'],"UTF-8");
        $temp['first'] = mb_convert_encoding($temp['first'],"UTF-8");
        $qcQuery = "SELECT * FROM qc_history WHERE ComponentID=7 AND Purchase_No=".$temp['PURCHASE_No']." ORDER BY QC_Date DESC";
        $qcresult = mysql_query($qcQuery);
        $temp2 = mysql_fetch_array($qcresult,MYSQL_ASSOC);
        if($temp2['QC_StatusID']== 20 && $temp2['MadeAt']==$madeAt ){//$temp2['QC_StatusID']== 20 &&
            //=====================Change the date format to week:day===============================//
            $temp2['formatedBCWExpected'] = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($day,strtotime($temp2['BCWExpected'])));
            $tep_time = date_sub(date_create($temp2['BCWExpected']),date_interval_create_from_date_string($day));
            $time = explode(':',date_format($tep_time,'W:w'));
            $week = (int)$time[0];
            $weekday = (int)$time[1];
            if($weekday == 0){
                $weekday = 5;
            }
            if($weekday == 6){
                $weekday = 5;
            }

            $temp2['WDdate'] = $week.':'.$weekday;
            //=======================End of Change the date format to week:day===============================//
            $temp['qc_history'] = $temp2;
            $temp['cname'] = $temp['first'].' '.$temp['surname'];

            if($temp['PURCHASE_No'] == $inPogressOrderNo){
                $returnArray['inprocessOrder'] = $temp;
            }
            else{
                array_push($orderArray, $temp);
            }

        }
    }
}
$returnArray['allOrder'] =  $orderArray;
return $returnArray;
}
?>
```

**I have tried the following**:

I have used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144302/store-array-in-while-loop-to-use-outside) to understand how to reference and update an array outside of a while loop

I have tried including a check for whether $inProgressArray is empty in the while loop like this.

```
 while($inProgressArray = mysql_fetch_array($inProgressResult,MYSQL_ASSOC)||empty($inProgressArray))
```

however, there is an item in leg_prod_inprogress and it's not shown in the $inProgressArray outside the loop.

**Editted 16/11/17 16:13 GMT: Added the details of legProductionAllRecords.php**

**Editted 2 17/11/17 08:43 GMT: Added the return statement of the return array of the function**

Comment: _Note:_ Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: You're currently overwriting all the variables on each iteration. Do you mean do that? You're also setting the `$orderArray` from a response from an, for us, unknown function so it's pretty hard for us to see what actually is happening here.

Comment: The usage of this function is unavoidable as I have several pages written in PHP 5.4.4.

I'm trying to populate the arrays:

$orderArray = array();
$inProgressArray = array()

with what is shown in the while loop.

Comment: Edited to include the details of legProductionAllRecords.php

Comment: Your function doesn't actually return any data, so your `$allArray` will always be null.

Comment: Hi, editted to include the return statement

Comment: Does that mean that this is not the full code?

Comment: yes, for index.php. the tableObj is a lot bigger, but I feel the concern is that orderArray in the data variable in the tableObj is unable to reference $orderArray when the while loop has no more items in the leg_prod_inprogress table.

Comment: As I've pointed out before, you're currently overwriting the variable `$orderArray` on each iteration, so it will _always_ only contain the result of the _last_ iteration.

Comment: The `if ($inProgressArray != false)` is useless, since the while loop only iterates through actual results. If it was false, the iteration would never even occur and that if statement would never be executed at all, so the `if` and the `else` can be removed.